# What are the first names of S. F. Buck?

Tags: citations, personal-name

**What are the first names of S. F. Buck?** He/She has several publications [1](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2984099),[2](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/animal-science/article/prediction-of-lean-percentage-of-pigs-of-bacon-weight-from-carcass-measurements/A1D2D35C623EEC2E6087D88307A3BE99),[3](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-agricultural-science/article/comparison-of-pigs-slaughtered-at-three-different-weights-i-carcass-quality-and-performance/BBABAFACAC258A6B549B63E5A65935C7),[4](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3150180),[5](https://www.cabdirect.org/cabdirect/abstract/19662703260),[6](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/journal-of-agricultural-science/article/use-of-rainfall-temperature-and-actual-transpiration-in-some-cropweather-investigations/97314AE5D3CEC3E9D3111FFEDDBD07FE),[7](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2985917). I tried to find the author on the pages listed and also in articles citing him/her, but in vain. General strategies on how to find first names are welcomed too.

Comment: Are you trying to find this person's first name for citation purpose? If yes, the question [Should I cite author names as they appear in the journal or as I know them to be complete?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/10926/546) might be helpful to you.

Comment: You may also want to look at the question [How to find out the first name of a professor whose home page lists only first initial?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/36820/546)

Comment: Also the following discussion may be of interest: https://pubpeer.com/publications/1DF3DECCEDE71B68C1D1ACA9B07336

Comment: @scaaahu Unfortunately, I don't have access to https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/.

Comment: Is there a university library near your residence or workplace?

Comment: @Qaswed I have added a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/36820/how-to-find-out-the-first-name-of-a-professor-whose-home-page-lists-only-first-i#comment272408_36821) to that answer that gives an alternative solution that does not require mathscinet.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Thank you. My impression is, that you receive exactly what you put in (+ a link to the article). I found https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=MR0117832 which gives me a link, but no (additional) information about the author.

Comment: @Qaswed True, at least in this case: their database does not contain the first name of that author. But if it does, then you get it back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to Google Scholar, the author's first name is Samuel.

To find this, I did the following:

- Do a Google Scholar search for one of S. F. Buck's papers; I chose the following paper which was linked in a comment above: A Method of Estimation of Missing Values in Multivariate Data Suitable for use with an Electronic Computer
- Click on the "cite" link (quote symbol) at the Google Scholar result for the above paper
- The MLA and Chicago citation style formats both list the author's first name as Samuel

Comment: I overlooked this nice littel button. However I want to point out, that this is only "save" when used on the article actually cited. For example the article "Report on a Study of Environmental Factors associated with Lung Cancer and Bronchitis Mortality in Areas of North East England." was coauthored by a Stephan Frank Buck.

Comment: @Qaswed What are you trying to explain?

Comment: Suppose you want to know who wrote "The prediction of lean percentage of pigs of bacon weight from carcass measurements" you find it was "S. F. Buck". Now the button mentioned also only states "S. F. Buck". If you now look up who wrote "A method of estimation of missing values in multivariate data suitable for use with an electronic computer" you find "Samuel F. Buck". But if you look up "Report on a Study of Environmental Factors associated with Lung Cancer and Bronchitis Mortality in Areas of North East England", you find "Stephan Frank Buck".

Comment: So the publications are written by different individual, who share the same abbreviated name.